# Why can't HTML import this image?

Tags: html, image, import, path, src

If i put this command in HTML in the div section it should work but does anybody know why it doesn't?

```
<img src="D:\School\ICT\Semester 2\Webtechnieken\short_hair_silhouette.jpeg" alt="profielfoto"/>
```

Comment: it's REALLY probably that the path is wrong

Comment: What research did you do, and where did you get stuck while doing your research? This is an easily-Googlable question, and is probably off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Your path should not include a space (Semester 2). You could use a pathname relative to the folder the html file is in. EDIT: The second part was wrong, thanks to admdrew for pointing it out.

Comment: maybe you can provide a code sample to go with the explanations